# deleting a string from screen in assembly 8086 emulator

Tags: string, assembly, graphics, emu8086

im writing a game in asembly 8086 for a school project. i am using graphics mode since its a game. in the game i want to print to the screen a string and then erase it from the screen. assuming i know the strings position is there a better way of doing this rather than look for the pixels and paint them?

i have tried color oover the string but its not accurate and i would want to change the string it will not work. i also thought to rewrite the string in the background color but it seems like least good idea to do and the least "programish" thing to do.

Comment: Set the pixels within the bounding box of the string to the background color.

Comment: There are two ways to draw simple graphics on background image: 1) Redraw underlying part of frame (or entine frame) every time something changed. When you need to display a string, draw it. When you need to "delete" a string, redraw part of the frame or entire frame without a string. 2) Save part of the frame before drawing a string. When you need to "delete" a string, restore saved part of the frame. Of course, if you draw on solid background, instead of saving and restoring you can just draw rectangle filled with background color.

Comment: How do you print the string on the screen? Are you using BIOS character output? If you do, then erasing the text string is just a simple matter of printing an equally long string of space characters.